# How to integrate count beside Like button?

Tags: html, facebook, increment

Here is the code for like button, i want to increment a counter each time its clicked.

```
<form method="POST" action="/like/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" value="{{i.id}}" name="mid" />
    <input type="hidden" value="{{i.comment}}" name="comment" />
    <input type="submit" value="LIKE-{{i.num_like}}" name="like" style="position:absolute;left:428px;margin-top:-18px;"/>
</form>
```

So can you please assist me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var Clicks = 0 ;
function AddClick(){
Clicks = Clicks + 1;
document.getElementById('CountedClicks').innerHTML = Clicks + ' Hits';
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<span id="CountedClicks">0 Hits</span><br>
<button style="background-color:green" onclick="AddClick()">Count Your Hit</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Something like that you would have to apply it to your button style, but thats the idea.